# Weak References stays alive

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, weak-references

I have an interface: IRemoteDataChangedListener

```
public interface IRemoteDataChangedListener<TData>
{
    void DataReceived(TData newData);
}
```

And a class, RealtimeEventService

```
public class RealtimeEventService : IRealtimeEventService
{
    private readonly IEventListener listener;

    private readonly List<Tuple<Type, WeakReference>> dataCreated;

    public RealtimeEventService(IEventListener eventListener)
    {
        this.dataCreated = new List<Tuple<Type, WeakReference>>();
        this.listener = eventListener;
        this.listener.EventReceived += this.ListenerOnEventReceived;
    }

    private void ListenerOnEventReceived(EventMessage message)
    {
        Type type = message.GetType();

        if (type == typeof(NotificationReadEventMessage))
        {
            this.DataChanged((NotificationReadEventMessage)message);
        }
    }

    public void SubscribeDataChanged<TEventMessage>(IRemoteDataChangedListener<TEventMessage> dataChangedListener) where TEventMessage : EventMessage, new()
    {
        this.dataCreated.Add(Tuple.Create(typeof(TEventMessage), new WeakReference(dataChangedListener)));
    }

    internal void DataChanged<TKey>(TKey newData)
        where TKey : class, new()
    {
        LoopAndFilter<TKey>(this.dataCreated, listener => listener.DataReceived(newData));
    }

    private static void LoopAndFilter<TKey>(ICollection<Tuple<Type, WeakReference>> collection,
        Action<IRemoteDataChangedListener<TKey>> success) where TKey : class
    {
        foreach (var reference in collection.ToArray())
        {
            if (!reference.Item2.IsAlive)
            {
                collection.Remove(reference);
                continue;
            }

            if (reference.Item1 != typeof(TKey))
                continue;

            success((IRemoteDataChangedListener<TKey>)reference.Item2.Target);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Whenever I create a test class that inherits IRemoteDataChangedListener with NotificationReadEventMessage as generic argument, and use an instance of this class with SubscribeDataChanged(), it gets hooked up just fine, and the method gets called.

Problem is, when I set the instance reference to null and run GC.Collect(), it should then be null, and the next time RealtimeEventService's LoopAndFilter method runs, it should detect that it is no longer alive, and remove the Weakreference from the list.

However it does not. When I inspect the value (In LoopAndFilter), after setting the instance reference to null in the test, the value still shows up as Alive being true.

And now I've been staring at this code for hours, and I simply cannot find anywhere I'd have a strong reference to the class...

Any help?

@Edit: Unit test (Using the Moq and Should libraries):

```
public class RealtimeEventServiceTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void VerifyWeakReferencesWorksAsIntended()
    {
        var eventListenerMock = new Mock<IEventListener>();
        IRealtimeEventService service = new RealtimeEventService(eventListenerMock.Object);

        bool called = false;
        RemoteDataTest dataChangedListener = new RemoteDataTest();
        dataChangedListener.Called += (sender, args) => called = true;
        service.SubscribeDataChanged(dataChangedListener);

        called.ShouldBeFalse();
        ((RealtimeEventService)service).DataChanged(new NotificationReadEventMessage());
        called.ShouldBeTrue();

        called = false;
        dataChangedListener = null;
        GC.Collect();

        called.ShouldBeFalse();
        ((RealtimeEventService)service).DataChanged(new NotificationReadEventMessage());
        called.ShouldBeFalse();
    }
}

public class RemoteDataTest : IRemoteDataChangedListener<NotificationReadEventMessage>
{
    public event EventHandler Called;

    public void DataReceived(NotificationReadEventMessage newData)
    {
        if (Called != null) Called(this, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: try replacing your anon function with a real one  listener => listener.DataReceived(newData) often they can hide 'clever'  compiler stuff

Comment: Not the source of your problem but your `reference.Item2.IsAlive` code is bad. You have a race condition where the object could be GCed betweent the IsAlive check and `reference.Item2.Target`. The better option is to do `var item = reference.Item2.Target; if(item == null) { collection.Remove(reference); continue }` to get a potential strong reference to the object before you check if the item was GCed or not (`.Target` will return null if the object was collected)

Comment: This is weird. When I run this exact same code on my home PC, it passes just fine. My home PC have better hardware than my work PC, but that shouldn't affect code, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, when I got home and compiled it at home, it ran just fine. And when I got back to work, it worked fine there as well.

Guess it's just one of those spooky bugs that magically vanish at inexplicable times. I'm just glad to be rid of it.

I did take the advice of Ewan & Scott Chamberlain, so thanks for that!